# Normalizing Spring Resource for use with JUnit & war?

Tags: spring

I'm probably thinking about this incorrectly, but here's what I'm up against:

I'm injecting Spring Resource objects into my app that give me the location of security certificates, for example:`<property name="certificateResource" value="SomeCert.p12" />` where certificateResource is of type `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`

Running under JUnit the Resource is a classpath resource and everything is fine. When deployed as a war under Tomcat the the Resource is in a Servlet Context and requires `WEB-INF/classes/` prepended to the certificate.

I've tried a number of Resource prefix and wildcard combinations but can't come-up with a single string that satisfies both contexts. So far the "solution" is to override the bean definition in `src/test/resources/test-applicationContext.xm`l but that means maintaining the strings in two locations.

Any pointers to better solutions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what prefixes have you tried exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to make a small but descriptive application using spring-test and spring-webmvc and using resources referenced in xml configs while these xml's are reused by production and testing spring configurations. Here is what I recieved: [github.com/isopov/spring-resource-test](https://github.com/isopov/spring-resource-test)

The central is the referencing of the prodcution xml config from the testing config:

```
<import resource="file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml" />
```

it is also possible to not import one xml from the other, but give each test several configs:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-applicationContext.xml",
                       "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml" })
```

the resource itself resides in `src/main/resources` (I assumed you are using Maven or something derived from the "Standard Directory Layout") so is always accessible with `"classpath:hello.txt"` from any spring config.

I tested this with maven build, as web-application and running UTs inside Eclipse.

Comment: Ivan if I'm following you correctly this is pretty much what I have, a test-appliationContext.xml that overrides the location when I run JUnit. What I'm looking for is a way to define the locations only once in a single context file and have them work as either a classpath resource or a Servlet Context resource.

Comment: Please, take a look once again - I have the path to the resource specified only once in the "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml" file. Two possibilities that I described are about importing this file to the test context. And again - only one way should be used, not both at once.

If I misunderstood the situation in some way - please help with clarifying it a bit.